# Find out limit of the function

Tags: limits

We should estimate value on
$
\left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}
\right)
$

$$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(x \cdot \left[ \frac {1}{x} \right] \right)
$$
where $ \left[ \frac {1}{x} \right]$ - integer part of $ \frac {1}{x} $

Comment: Sound good. What is the value on these intervals then?

Comment: @Winther It was just a hint, I do not know how to use it.

Comment: Since $1/x \in (n,n+1)$ you can compute $[1/x]$. And a number in this interval satisfy $\frac{1}{n+1} < x < \frac{1}{n}$. Combine these two facts and use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Totum_Revolutum What is the meaning of the square brackets? Does $\left[ \frac {1}{x} \right]$ denote the integer part of $\frac{1}{x}$? If so, please specify it. Some people may think that it is just a square bracket, and then the limit is trivially $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $\;\{x\}=$ the fractional value of $\;x\;$ , we have that

$$x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}\implies\lfloor x\rfloor= x-\{x\}$$

so

$$x\left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor=x\left(\frac1x-\left\{\frac1x\right\}\right)=1-x\left\{\frac1x\right\}$$

and now you may want to apply the claim: "The limit of a product of a function whose limit is zero times a bounded function is zero" ...